# Compass: Syntax error: Undefined mixin 'user-select'

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I get the follow error when trying to use the mixin 'user-select'. I'm using version 0.12.2 which I'm pretty sure supports [user-select](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/user_interface/) from compass. So why can't I use this mixin?

**Error**

```
 Syntax error: Undefined mixin \'user-select\'
```

**Includes**

```
// css3
    @import "compass/css3";
    @import "partials/deposit";
```

**Call**

```
//File: partials/_deposit.scss
@include user-select(none);
```

So why can't I use this mixin?

Comment: Instead of trying to import full `compass/css3`, have you tried `@import "compass/css3/user-interface"` to test?

Comment: I just tried that before reading the comment. But add it as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: Why don't you just do `@import 'compass';`? It would save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Don't want bloat wear :|

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [`@import "compass/css3/"`](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/), this is the list of the imported things:

- **Appearance** – Specify the CSS3 appearance property.
- **Background Clip** – Specify the background clip for all browsers.
- **Background Origin** – Specify the background origin for all browsers.
- **Background Size** – Specify the background size for all browsers.
- **Border Radius** – Specify the border radius for all browsers.
- **Box** – This module provides mixins that pertain to the CSS3 Flexible Box.
- **Box Shadow** – Specify the box shadow for all browsers.
- **Box Sizing** – Specify the box sizing for all browsers.
- **Columns** – Specify a columnar layout for all browsers.
- **Filter** – Specify the (image) filter for all browsers.
- **Font Face** – Specify a downloadable font face for all browsers.
- **Hyphenation** – Mixin for breaking space and injecting hypens into overflowing text
- **Images** – Specify linear gradients and radial gradients for many browsers.
- **Inline Block** – Declare an element inline block for all browsers.
- **Opacity** – Specify the opacity for all browsers.
- **CSS Regions** – Specify CSS Regions for supported browsers.
- **Text Shadow** – Specify the text shadow for all browsers.
- **Transform** – Specify transformations for many browsers.
- **Transition** – Specify a style transition for all browsers.

From this, we can say that *Compass User Interface* (`css3/user-interface`) isn't bundled with `compass/css3` thus you need to call it also, after the css3 call:

```
@import "compass/css3"
@import "compass/css3/user-interface"
//other imports
```

---

### Update

#### Compass 0.13.alpha.10 onwards

Looks like the 0.13.alpha.10 Compass [imports user-interface as well](https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/commit/e32559198405075c5a7bfd05cdaf49753301ad47) since the [documentation page](http://beta.compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/) was updated:

- **User Interface** – Declare an element inline block for all browsers.

Also was added animation as well:

- **Animation** – Specify the CSS3 animation property and all its sub-properties.

Therefore just `@import "compass/css3"` is enough now.

Comment: oooo, very nice. Somehow i missed this documentation. +1 for that alone :)

Comment: @JamieHutber Just did an update to the answer, seems they finally added `user-interface` as part of `css3` import :P

Comment: wohoooo makes my question redundant, which imo is living the dream!

Comment: @JamieHutber Heh at least leave it there, people with old Compass will still have problems, look how many upvotes I got lol, seems quite common the problem.